# How long is a "whole day" for work purposes?

Tags: magic-items, crafting, time, anima-beyond-fantasy

In Table 7 on page 15 of the Prometheum Exxet, there is an entry for "one whole day".  I know that if I spend a *week* crafting each item, it takes an 8-hour period per day to do.  How much, though, is "one whole day"?

Comment: thanks for the [time] tag, @V2Blast.

Answer (score 2):

The rules on forging state

> "Keep in mind that a day of work is equal to 12 hours work in an adequately equipped workshop or smithy."

Arguing from that, one day of work would be 12 hours of mostly uninterrupted work, allowing for short breaks like eating and whatnot.

Comment: Do you have a source or an argument for this?

Comment: Double checked the book... The section discussing forging says this: "Keep in mind that a day of work is equal to 12 hours work in an
adequately equipped workshop or smithy." 12 hours seems almost excessively high though.

Comment: Submitted an edit that adds the quote you just quoted to the post.